# PHP DOM removing the tag (not content)

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

```
$mystring="This is mystring. <a href='http://www.google.com'>Google.</a>"; 
$dom = new DOMDocument; 
$dom->loadHTML($mystring); 
$xPath = new DOMXPath($dom); 
$nodes = $xPath->query('//a');
if($nodes->item(0)) { 
    $nodes->item(0)->parentNode->removeChild($nodes->item(0)); 
} 
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

I want to get output:

> This is mystring. Google.

But i got just:

> This is mystring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
if($nodes->item(0)) {
    $node = $nodes->item(0);
    $node->parentNode->replaceChild(new DOMText($node->textContent), $node); 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Or, Use simple techniques to do simple things.

Here is an alternative to strip_tags()

```
preg_replace('#<a.*?>(.*?)</a>#i', '\1', $text)
```

Comment: preg_replace causes some performance problems with my software but thanks for your opinion.

Comment: Regex is the worst way to handle html.

Answer (score -2):

"Google" is a child of the node you are trying to remove. So this behavior is expected. I think what you want is to use PHP's [strip_tags](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php) function.

```
echo strip_tags("This is mystring. <a href='http://www.google.com'>Google.</a>");
```

Comment: actually i've many tags but i want to unstrip some tags. this function strips all tags something like div, p, b, blablabla. but thanks for your opinion.

Comment: The second parameter can specify which tags to leave. For instance, to leave in span, p and div:

    echo strip_tags($string, '<span><p><div>");

Comment: I'm sorry to downvote you but I feel compelled to, because strip_tags with certain tags permitted is a security problem because it does not allow to strip attributes.